# Checkbox Recaptcha is Showing Image Recaptcha Instead

Tags: image, checkbox, recaptcha

My recaptcha form was working great.  Now it is requiring users select images instead of just checking the box that they are not a robot.

**Form code is:**

```
                        <div class="contact-form"><form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                            <h4>Contact Form</h4>
                            <form>
    <input type="text" value="Full Name" name="fullname" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
    <input type="text" value="Email" name="email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}">
    <input type="text" value="Telephone" name="telephone" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Telephone';}">
    <textarea type="text" value="Message" name="message" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message</textarea><br />&nbsp;<br />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc8880UAAAAAPZy3GTijiEmi1Y6fbj21ExMm4IA"></div>
    <br />&nbsp;<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
```

**Header code is:**//script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer>  (starts with a < )

Help!